# MySQL loose comparison, WHERE on varchar field with integer value yields unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, string, varchar

I recently discovered an interesting bug in a program, which selects data for a specific customer using their private key. Consider the following:

```
SELECT `id` FROM (`customers`) WHERE `authenticationKey` = '#09209!ko2A-' LIMIT 1
```

The key is provided at request-time, and properly sanitized before put to query. However, failing to providing a key (which should be caught before; ignore that), would yield a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT `id` FROM (`customers`) WHERE `authenticationKey` = 0 LIMIT 1
```

Which would return a row from the `customers`-table - despite it having a proper, string, key stored, such as in the first  example.

The `authenticationKey`-field is of the type `VARCHAR(1024)`.

My guess is that this has something to do with loose comparasion. What is causing this problem, and how can it properly be avoided?

Comment: The application creating this query is running CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord. It's not currently using PDO/MySQLi, since it's a legacy-application.

Comment: Did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL will try and coerce data to a comparable type. I this case it will try and convert strings to numbers. Any strings that it can't make sense of default to 0.

Do

```
select 0 = 'banana'
```

to see this in action.

Making your query compare to `'0'` instead of `0` would fix it.

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24803)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

MySQL implicitly converts the leading chars of `authenticationKey` to int until it finds a char that's not a valid number. I guess all rows that start with a non-numeric char are treated as 0.

For instance, this yields 'b', since the coerced int value is 1:

```
select (case when '1abc' = 0 then 'a' else 'b' end);
```

But this yields 'a', since the leading char isn't a valid number, so the coerced int value is 0:

```
select (case when '#1abc' = 0 then 'a' else 'b' end);
```

This should be avoided by the application. Why you query with `0` when no key is given, after all?