# MySQL returning results when it shouldn't

Tags: mysql

I am absolutely perplexed by this. We have a table of API keys, the create SQL is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `api_keys` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `app` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have two rows, the insert SQL is below:

```
INSERT INTO `api_keys` (`id`, `key`, `ip`, `app`, `active`)
VALUES
(1,'xxwxMKEkAHTcF9P3qQOOvfeuK0aMrd0GFLOoR3O6','10.0.0.1','Test App',1),
(2,'CeMbGnWO4aC4RuI7EJyZaNwidUI4nsEGEvgFNGzG','10.0.0.2','Test App 2',1);
```

When I run the following query, I get a result when it should be empty. I really don't understand it.

```
SELECT *
FROM `api_keys`
WHERE `ip` = '10.0.0.1'
AND `key` = 0
AND `active` = 1;
```

It seems that when 0 is passed as the key it returns a record, which it shouldn't do. Any ideas or advice will be received with gratitude. The MySQL version is 5.6 and runs on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Your `key` field is a VARCHAR and yet you compare it with a number. I suspect some kind of automatic datatype conversion to be the culprit (any non-numeric string will convert to 0). What happens if you change your condition to `AND key = ''`?

Comment: Check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895263/mysql-loose-comparison-where-on-varchar-field-with-integer-value-yields-unexpec, I think is what you look for

Answer (score 0):

You should try null value insted of 0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error in my enviroment. What happens is when you compare your field key with 0 the MySQL engine "converts" your field, so as it's a varchar it'll just be converted to 0, that really matches the 0 that you comparing.

If you put the 0 between double-quotes you'll solve it, try it:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM `api_keys`
WHERE 
    `ip` = '10.0.0.1'
    AND `key` = '0'
    AND `active` = 1;
```

Here we are expliciting saying that's a varchar and not a integer.